# undifined function associated to a mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm using a Matlab code (not developed by me) that calls a function associated to a mex file (they have the same noun). However, I'm getting an error stating that the function is undefined.

Should I execute a specified command before I call this function? (I'm using MAC OS X and Matlab R 2016a).

Here is the code, the error is at the line calling the function fastmarchmex (i recall that the fastmarchmex.mexw64 and 32 is in the current folder):

```
rootdir  = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
addpath(fullfile(rootdir,'util'));
addpath(fullfile(rootdir,'sihks'));

load(fullfile(rootdir,'shapes','0001.scale.1.mat'),'shape'
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------    
%% SIHKS signature
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------
fprintf('preprocessing');
shape.idxs    = compute_vertex_face_ring(shape.TRIV');
ndesc         = 5;
[desc,shape] = signature(shape,'sihks');
fprintf('.');

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%% ISC settings
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------

rad     = 10;   % radius used for descriptor construction
nbinsr  = 5;    % number of rings
nbinsth = 16;   % number of rays

rr      = [1:nbinsr]/nbinsr*rad;
th      = [1:nbinsth]/nbinsth*2*pi;

fhs     = 2;         %% factor determining hardness of scale 
quantization

fha     = .01;       %% factors determining hardness of angle 
quantization

**shape.f_dns      = fastmarchmex('init', int32(shape.TRIV-1),         
double(shape.X(:)), double(shape.Y(:)), double(shape.Z(:)));**

vertex                                = 701;
shape                                 = 
fast_marching(vertex,shape,'vertex',0,1,shape.f_dns);

[in_ray,in_ring,shp,geod,directions]= get_net(shape,vertex,'scales',
[0,rr],'N_rays',length(th),'fhs',fhs,'fha',fha);

[dec_net] = get_descriptor_from_net(in_ray,in_ring,desc,shape.Av); 
fastmarchmex('deinit', shape.f_dns);


%% end of code, visualization of results 
a = -82.5000;
v = 18;

dind = 1;
figure(1); clf;  show_shape(shape,desc(:,dind));
hold on,scatter3(geod{1}(1,1),geod{1}(2,1),geod{1}
(3,1),'filled','SizeData',150,'Cdata',[1,0,0])

for k=[1:length(geod)]
   hold on;
   h = plot3(geod{k}(1,:),geod{k}(2,:),geod{k}(3,:));
   set(h,'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',2);
end
for r = [1:length(rr)]
   plot_ring(shape,rr(r));
end
title('Net around vertex')
view(-82.50,18)

figure(2); clf; plot_polarhist(squeeze(desc_net(dind,:,:)),rr,th,0);
```

Comment: Are the function and the mex file in your [working directory](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) or in your [path](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)?

Comment: yes of course they are

Comment: the file.m that is calling the function (functionA) associated to the mex file (functionAmex.mexw64) are in the same current folder

Comment: *"I'm using a Matlab code"* How are you using it? It's hard to help if you don't include your code in the question. Please do include your code.

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MATLAB R13 and later, which support Mac OS X, use the .mexmac extension 
on the Mac.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/65044)
So, you should recompile your Mex file for Mac now you have Windows version

Comment: I do not have the source for generating the mex files. I'll switch to linux to see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: You should try Windows. These Mex files were compiled for this OS

Comment: On Linux Ubuntu, i'm getting this error: Undefined function 'fastmarchmex' for input arguments of type 'int64'. This seems weird because I have both fastmarchmex.mexw64 and fastmarchmex.mexw32 in my directory

Comment: Again it is for Windows and only for Windows

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't understand that's only for Windows. I'll try on windows

Comment: Report the results please

Comment: It's good with Windows 7. There's no errors with Matlab R2013. Thank you